# Cov_ in javascript files, unsure which package, babel instanbul?

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'm unsure what package is causing additions in my source files when compiled to add things like this:

```
gcv = '__coverage__',
```

and

```
++cov_119g7nzanu.f[4];
++cov_119g7nzanu.s[26];
```

I suspect it's a testing package, but we don't do that yet, so I'd like to remove it until we do. Just not sure what to remove, I tried searching for it and found nothing. We're using gulp if that helps, but I hope someone will recognize these additions without having to scan a whole package.json file

Edit 1: It looks like Babel coverage from the plugin "instanbul" (https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul) but I removed this from my package.json, rebuilt and still have it. Any ideas how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this. It's using istanbul, and to turn off the coverage, go in the .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "istanbul"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and remove the istanbul plugin:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "env": {

  }
}
```